# How to put java data into a json file?

Tags: java, json

I'm doing a school project (create a bus network), and they ask me to put the data (number of the bus and so on) into a json file.

Do you guys have a simple example for me please ? I'm using eclipse, and I tried to use the `org.json.simple.JSONObject;` library but it does not work.

Cordially

Comment: There are many libraries to convert a java object into Json. Probably the most widely used are Jackson and Gson. After you get a Json object then you can write it to a file.
Please share the code you are trying so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

[Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) is the de-facto standard library for reading and writing JSON with Java. It can also be used to read/write XML, YAML and other formats.

There are many tutorials on the web on how to use Jackson, such as http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/jackson-create-json/

General usage:

- Create/confiure a `ObjectMapper`
- Create your data beans, and optionally annotate them with Jackson annotations to fine-tune the serialization
- Serialize/deserialize your beans using the object mapper.

Sophisticated example which also shows how to serialize from/to other formats, and how to use custom serialization:
https://github.com/pwalser75/json-xml-yaml-test

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [Java – Write to File](https://www.baeldung.com/java-write-to-file) and [How do I create a file and write to it in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-do-i-create-a-file-and-write-to-it-in-java)

With a POJO:

```
public class Data {

    private final String name;
    private final String id;

    public Data(final String name, final String id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

And this code using Jackson and [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html):

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Data data = new Data("abc", "123");
String jsonData = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(data);
Path path = Paths.get("myFile");
Files.write(path, jsonData.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Comment: Thanks. If my data is inside an ArrayList, how can I put all that inside this json file ? For example, I've inside an ArrayList all the bus stop, in another one the bus inside the network and so on.

Comment: You can create an object with the two lists: "Data myData = new Data(list1, list2);" or use the lists directly: "System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myList);"

Comment: Which import I need to be able to use this code ? Since it does not propose me an import :/

Comment: `import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;` which can be imported with the [jackson-databind Maven dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.9)

Comment: I'm not using maven, since the project is well advanced. it says when I put it "create class ObjectMapper in package com.faster...." :/

Comment: I finally success to have those import. But I can not find the one for Data, it says it does not exist..

Comment: You have to create the class `Data` defined above

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the example posted here you can see how to handle lists:
[How to construct JSON data in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56805274/how-to-construct-json-data-in-java)

You can also just put an ArrayList as value instead an array of Strings. Jackson will do the rest for you.

Comment: I need to create 2 new class ? I first thought that I just need to put some lines into my files

Comment: You dont need to create model classes if you use generic HashMaps which i already posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56805274/how-to-construct-json-data-in-java

Comment: well, it does not recognize "ObjectMapper", which import I need to use ?

Comment: yes you have to download or import it. If you use maven you gould just put a 

```<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>```

Take care to take the latest dependency you can look it up at https://search.maven.org/

Comment: I'm not using maven :/

Comment: than grap the binary from somewhere - you really should use maven nowadays. You need to find com.fasterxml.jackson.core module which contains databinding.

Comment: well thanks, I don't know how to do it then, i'll try to find something

Answer (score 0):

Here is a file1.txt content:

```
{
"Name": "crunchify.com",
"Author": "App Shah",
"Company List": [
    "Compnay: eBay",
    "Compnay: Paypal",
    "Compnay: Google"
]
}
```

Java Code:

```
    package com.crunchify.tutorials;

    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
    import org.json.simple.JSONObject;



    public class CrunchifyJSONFileWrite {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("Name", "crunchify.com");
        obj.put("Author", "App Shah");

        JSONArray company = new JSONArray();
        company.add("Compnay: eBay");
        company.add("Compnay: Paypal");
        company.add("Compnay: Google");
        obj.put("Company List", company);

        // try-with-resources statement based on post comment below :)
        try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("/Users/<username>/Documents/file1.txt")) {
            file.write(obj.toJSONString());
            System.out.println("Successfully Copied JSON Object to File...");
            System.out.println("\nJSON Object: " + obj);
        }
    }
}
```